# datepicker add a day to the end date

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, calendar

Appreciate any help. Have searched many pages on this forum about Javascript datepicker dates. They all include two textbox calendars and not a compound bootstrap one.

I have a compound calendar (one input and a popup comes up displaying two boxes for from and to date and an apply button). When I search, it works, as long as the date I am searching for doesn't end on the date I am searching, for example, searching for 06/12/2015-06/18/2015 will not include results from the 18th June (06/18/2015). This is also the case if I enter the same date for start and end dates.

SUMMARY: need a way to set "start" and "end" so that I can add a day to the "end" day:

```
$('#picup-range').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(start, end) {
            submitFilter();

            });


function submitFilter() {

        $('#filter').submit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up having to change Java database query that provided the data.